# How to expose an open directory on/using github pages?

Tags: html, github, web, webserver, github-pages

I would like to know if it's possible to expose an open directory with list of files on github pages? or if oficially it isn't supported, is there any way, such as some project that generates a list of files within its own directory, so that when clicked the files would start downloading? because I have many of them, and manually linking all of them, for my project file would take a very long time.

I tried leaving an open directory without a html file in it, it gave a 404 page by github, was expecting a generated page with the list of files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.